# Redirect from datasheet view in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, redirect, datasheet

I have a sharepoint 2013 list. When the user clicks on edit this list to open it in  a datasheet view...after making changes when clicked on **stop** ,the data should be saved and redirect to another page. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this possible at all? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom new list form.

Remove/Comment the save button and add new save button instead

Comment: I want it from the datasheet view..not the sharepoint form

Comment: That is not recommended Dheeraj . Cause they can probably insert unnecessary item in the list